# Does my AD domain name have to match the domain on Office 365?

Tags: active-directory, office365

This is my first question on Stack Overflow as I could not find anything online regarding my issue.

I work for a new company and when we originally started, an Active Directory domain was not necessary for operations. We did, however, sign up for Office 365.

My question is, does the AD FQDN have to be in the format of internal.mycompany.com so that the email accounts match up or can it be something like mycompany.local? I know this might be a really basic question but this is my first time working on something like this.

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

My company is using a .local DN. It works fine with Office365.
The fact is, if you select username@yourcompany.local from on-premise AD as logon name, you will need to use the same username@yourcompany.local to login your Office365 account.